# Regex Ignore First 6 Matches Of Character

Tags: regex

This is my string: `/my/name/is/the/following/string/name.lastname/file.txt`

I want to extract `name.lastname` from this string.

I've tried using `\/.*\.app`, but this selects:
 `/my/name/is/the/following/string/name.lastname`

**How can I ignore the first 6 or 7 `/`'s?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few good answers going for you. Here's one that uses positive look ahead `(?=)`, with the end of string `$`.

```
([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+$)
```

The benefit here is you can have as many folders prior to your last folder, and it will still work.

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qiuz3T/2)

If we break this down, you have a

- capturing group: `([^\/]+)`, and a
- positive look ahead `(?=\/[^\/]+$)`.

The capturing group will match everything *except* `^` a forward slash `/`, one to as many times possible `+`. This would actually capture every string between a forward slash, so that's why we use the positive lookahead.

The biggest factor in your positive lookahead is that it looks for the end of your string `$` (signified by the dollar sign). It will look for everything after a forward slash `/` (hence the `(?=\/` portion), then it will ensure no other forward slashes exists but match all other characters `[^\/]` one to unlimited times `+` to the end of the string `$`.

Comment: Wow. Could you please explain just quickly how this regex code works? Cheers! Using this ^_^

Comment: Sure, one moment

Comment: Take your time.

Comment: This assumes that the final folder is the target.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen true, I read it that way however, because OP stated first 6 or 7, which meant to me that he wanted the last folder as in the amount of parent folders were dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a repeating pattern to consume, but not match, the first six components of the path:

```
(?:\/[^\/]+){6}\/([^\/]+)
```

Your item will be available in the first capture group.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more flexible solution, i.e. the string between
**last 2 slashes** (not necessarily 6th and 7th), you can use:

```
\/([^\/]+)\/(?!.*\/)
```

Meaning:

- `\/` - A slash.
- `([^\/]+)` - Capturing group No 1 - a sequence of chars other than a slash.
  This is what you actually want to match.
- `\/` - Another slash.
- `(?!` - Negative lookahead for:
- `.*\/` - a sequence of any chars and a slash.
- `)` - End of negative lookahead (works even in JavaScript version of Regex).

The above negative lookahead actually means: *Nowhere further
can occur any slash*.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this ,it will match 6 or 7 th position

```
([a-z\.]*)(?=\/[a-z]*\.txt)

(?=\/[a-z]*\.txt) to check ends with .txt
([a-z\.]*) CapturingGroup to capture the name
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Z7P6Qa/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
((\/)[a-b]*).[^\/]{12}
```

Hi, Please try the above Reg ex, it should return what you expecting